# How to use increment operator in reactJS

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm performing the increment operation in react component on each iteration by using increment operator. I'm not able to perform the increment operator in react component. Kindly help me to get the solution for this.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './js/components/Header';
import './App.css';
import './dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';
import Request from 'superagent';
import { browserHistory  } from 'react-router';


export default class Performance extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        fullName : cookie.load('fullName'),
        empId : cookie.load('empId'),
        userResults : [{
  "sectionTitle": "Customer Orientation",
  "isMandatory": 0,
  "question": [{
   "qusId": 1,
   "question": "Number of customer ",
   "weightage": 15,
    }]
   }]
    };   
}

render() {
        const userCount = 0;    
        return ( 
        <div >
        <Header />  
            <div className="container ">
                <form className="form-signin1"> 
                {  
                   this.state.userResults.map(function(res)
                   {
                 
                 var questions = res.question.map(function(res1){
                 return (
                  <tr>
                   <td>{res1.question}<input type="checkbox" value="" name={'ques_check_box_'+[res1.qusId]}/>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                  )
               });
               return (
               <div className="row">
               { userCount ++ } //increment by one for each iteration
               <table className="table text-center" >
               <thead>
               <th width="400">Deliverables</th>
               <th>Justifications</th>
               <th>Weightage</th>
               <th className="lastHead">Employee <br />Weightage</th>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
               {questions}
               </tbody>
               </table> 
               </div>
               )
          })
        }
        </form>
    </div> 
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of maintaining separate variable(`userCount`), You can make use of `index` parameter of `.map`.

Then `render` method will be like

```
render() {
    return ( < div >
        < Header / >
        < div className = "container " >
        < form className = "form-signin1" > {
          this.state.userResults.map(function(res, index) {

                var questions = res.question.map(function(res1) {
                      return ( < tr >
                        < td > {
                          res1.question
                        } < input type = "checkbox"
                        value = ""
                        name = {
                          'ques_check_box_' + [res1.qusId]
                        }
                        />
                    </td >
                        < /tr>
                  )
               });
               return (
               <div className="row">
               { index+1 } 
                        for each iteration < table className = "table text-center" >
                        < thead >
                        < th width = "400" > Deliverables < /th>
               <th>Justifications</th >
                        < th > Weightage < /th>
               <th className="lastHead">Employee <br / > Weightage < /th>
               </thead >
                        < tbody > {
                          questions
                        } < /tbody>
               </table >
                        < /div>
               )
          })
        }
        </form >
                        < /div> 
    </div >
                      );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You defined `userCount` as a constant. That implies the value should never change. That's not what you wanted.
2. <strike>The space between `userCount ++` has to be removed.</strike>

Comment: Your first point is correct but your second one isn't - the space doesn't make a difference.